# GraphQL query in PHP without libraries

Tags: php, graphql

Is it possible to convert an array or an object in PHP to a GraphQL query without importing a library?

I'm hoping for something that works like json_encode does for JSON.

e.g.

```
$array['products']['edges']['node']['handle'] = true;
$graphql = graphql_encode($array);
echo $graphql; // prints: {products(first: 10) { edges { node { handle }}}}
```

Maybe this would always be an oversimplification (e.g. I'm not quite sure how "(first: 10)" would be added to the array).

But I'm just looking for a simple way to start experimenting with GraphQL (and I don't have access to SSH or Composer on my shared hosting so it's not easy for me to add the right libraries).

Comment: I would suggest setting up local dev environment with WAMP/LAMP/MAMP to experiment with new stuff. Then you would have full access to all the tools and libs

Comment: The [standard GraphQL HTTP interface](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) is fairly simple and if you can make JSON-over-HTTP calls you don't strictly speaking need a GraphQL client library.

Comment: @EriksKlotins Thanks, I'm thinking about using my local dev to get the library and then upload via ftp. I'd like to start using it live as soon as possible.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you are suggesting that I just type out the queries, then that's always a possibility, but seems kind of silly to have to do that. That's how I did JSON to begin with, but not the best way when I'm doing something a bit more complicated.

Comment: Typical GraphQL usage in most languages in fact involves actually writing out the queries.  ("Like SQL", if that's a helpful analogy.)  A full-featured GraphQL library might have an object model for it but using that tends to be more complex and involves knowing GraphQL in detail anyways.

Comment: @DavidMaze oh, I did not know that. Thanks for the info!